# JAVA:How to implement lazy loading of sql with join statement?

Tags: java, sql-server, linq

for example,I have the sql with many join like this:

```
select * from TableA a left join TableB b on a.id=b.id left join TableC c on c.id=a.id where userid=123
```

Now I am trying to use java program to re-constructor the code like this(fake code).

```
List<TableA> a=sqlQuery("select * from tableA");
List<TableB> a=sqlQuery("select * from tableB");
var temp= a.Where(a.id==b.id&&a.userid==123);
```

I was a C# coder before,so I know EF or Linq has the lazy load mode to load context after all sql accomplished,like C#'s difference between IQueryable and ILIst, I don't know if Java can do the same thing,so anyone can help me?

Comment: This won't end well I'm afraid.  You should just execute the query itself in Java.

Comment: Am not expert in java, but if you can get the count of records to be shown in screen then use `OFFSET/FETCH` concept or Generate row_number for each record and use it for pagination

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen hi,my aim is to decouple the relationship from the "sql join" statement,so if execute the sql is not the perfect mind to do.because "join" means there are more or less different database or table,I just want to do it in program ,meanwhile decrease the memory use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JDBC APIs don't support that kind of thing, and if you tried to implement this yourself on top of JDBC, I imagine you would be in for a hard time.

There are some third-party libraries that offer aspects of Linq-to-SQL in the Java context.  This JOOQ blog post describes the problem, and offers some leads:

- https://blog.jooq.org/2013/07/01/linq-and-java/